# Pickle multy layer CNN in Theano, Lenet5

Tags: deep-learning, theano, conv-neural-network, image-recognition

I am new to deep learning, and I got a problem. 
I am using Theano for image recognition, and I want to create a prediction system using trained model.
I referenced LeNet5 [Convolutional Neural Networks (LeNet)](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html) and trained my own data, now I want to use the trained model for predicting new images.
In [Classifying MNIST digits using Logistic Regression](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/logreg.html) it described the way to pickle trained models, but it is just a logistic regression, not a multilayered CNN. In the same way I saved each layer, but I cant use it for prediction.
Please help me! 
Here is my code:

```
def predict():
"""
An example of how to load a trained model and use it
to predict labels.
"""

# load the saved model
#x = Data
x = T.matrix('x')
Data = x.reshape((1, 1, 32, 32))
layer0
layer1
layer2_input = layer1.output.flatten(2)
layer2
layer3

# compile a predictor function
predict_model = theano.function([layer0.input],
    layer0.output)
    #inputs=[layer0.input],
    #outputs=layer3.y_pred)

# We can test it on some examples from test test
#dataset='facedata_cross_6_2_6.pkl.gz'
#datasets = load_data(dataset)
#test_set_x, test_set_y = datasets[2]
#test_set_x = test_set_x.get_value()
#reshape=np.reshape(test_set_x[26],(28,28))
#plt.imshow(reshape)

predicted_values = predict_model(Data)
print("Predicted values for the first 10 examples in test set:")
print(predicted_values)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to save your model. The one I often to use is by pickle the weight and bias of each layer (the order is up to you):

```
f = file('Models/bestmodel.pickle','wb')
cPickle.dump(layer0.W.get_value(borrow=True),f,protocol=cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
cPickle.dump(layer1.W.get_value(borrow=True),f,protocol=cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
cPickle.dump(layer2.W.get_value(borrow=True),f,protocol=cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
...
cPickle.dump(layer0.b.get_value(borrow=True),f,protocol=cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)            
cPickle.dump(layer1.b.get_value(borrow=True),f,protocol=cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
cPickle.dump(layer2.b.get_value(borrow=True),f,protocol=cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
...
f.close()
```

then for prediction system, create a same model architecture and use saved model as initial value (with the same order as you saved):

```
f=file('Models/bestmodel.pickle','rb')
layer0.W.set_value(cPickle.load(f), borrow=True)
layer1.W.set_value(cPickle.load(f), borrow=True)
layer2.W.set_value(cPickle.load(f), borrow=True)
...
layer0.b.set_value(cPickle.load(f), borrow=True)
layer1.b.set_value(cPickle.load(f), borrow=True)
layer2.b.set_value(cPickle.load(f), borrow=True)
...
f.close()
```

Comment: That worked！Man, you are awesome! Thank you! I use the code like,#layer0 = pickle.load(open('best_model_layer0.pkl'))
#layer1 = pickle.load(open('best_model_layer1.pkl'))
#layer2 = pickle.load(open('best_model_layer2.pkl'))
#layer3 = pickle.load(open('best_model_layer3.pkl')) But every time it predicts as [0].  Your code figured out everything!

Comment: Okey.. glad it works :) if you think this is an accepted answer you can click accepted symbol ('v' check symbol) in my answer to inform the future reader

Comment: Yes I want to but my reputation is not enough :(

Comment: Wow seriously? I think accepting answer doesnt need minimum reputation, but it's okay